# Python Pandas, Running Sum, based on previous rows value and grouped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, cumulative-sum

I have a pandas dataframe along these lines, based on where a customer service case sits before being closed. Every time the case is edited and audit trial is captured. I want to generate a counter for each time the Department of a case changes from the department it was previously in.

| ID | Department | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Sales | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 |
| A | Sales | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 |
| A | Operations | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 |
| A | Sales | 04/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |
| B | Finance | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 |
| B | Risk | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 |

The output I want to achieve is shown below, the part I am struggling with is getting the 'Count of Department Change' value to increase when the ticket returns to a department it has already been in.

| ID | Department | Start Date | End Date | Count of Department Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Sales | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 | 0 |
| A | Sales | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 | 0 |
| A | Operations | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 | 1 |
| A | Sales | 04/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 | 2 |
| B | Finance | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 | 0 |
| B | Risk | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 | 1 |

Using the following code I am able to flag when the department changes for a given case.

```
df['Dept_Change_Count'] = np.where((df['Department'] != df['Department'].shift(1)) & (df['ID'] == df['ID'].shift(1)), '1', '0')
```

I'm thinking I could use the df['Dept_Change_Count'] and a running sum along the ID to generate the output I'm after but I haven't had much luck so far.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare previous and current row in `Department` per `ID` then again `group` by `ID` and calculate `cumsum` to generate counter

```
m = df['Department'] != df.groupby('ID')['Department'].shift()
df['Dept_Change_Count'] = m.groupby(df['ID']).cumsum() - 1
```

Alternative approach using a single `groupby` with lambda func to calculate cumsum:

```
df['Dept_Change_Count'] = df.groupby('ID')['Department']\
                            .apply(lambda s: (s != s.shift()).cumsum()) - 1
```

---

```
  ID  Department  Start Date    End Date  Dept_Change_Count
0  A       Sales  01/01/2022  02/01/2022                  0
1  A       Sales  02/01/2022  03/01/2022                  0
2  A  Operations  03/01/2022  04/01/2022                  1
3  A       Sales  04/01/2022  05/01/2022                  2
4  B     Finance  01/01/2022  02/01/2022                  0
5  B        Risk  02/01/2022  03/01/2022                  1
```